# Issue with creating windows 10 UAP project visual studio 2015

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2015

I have created a sample win10 Universal.
Initially project was created but its showing some reference missing error like 
**CS0246 The type or namespace name missing**
When I close the visual studio and re open the same project the solution is not able to load the project.
when I tried to reload the project its asking for me to install some missing platform sdk, When I press on the install, initially I goes to [this](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12514&pver=14.0&sbp=PlatformSDKMissing&plcid=0x409&o1=UAP,%20Version=10.0.0.0) link.

but I think since its not available its loading some default page.

I am not able to find what to install?
can any help on this?

Thanks.!

Comment: Is your OS updated to the latest version of windows 10 preview?

Comment: @ bell no,my current build is 10041.Initially I tried with the latest version available which is 10049,but hyper-V is not working with that that's why I reverted to this version of OS

Comment: did you installed any tools other than this VS CTP.

Comment: @ joseph yes installed the UAP platform Sdk,then only we will get templates to develop the win10 apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also having an issue something like this.I tried the below things and finally got worked.
You can try out this work around.

First uninstall your windows 10.
Download the latest technical preview from [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/preview-iso).

Follow [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-ctp-vs) instructions.